# Why the object never stop rolling?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Rolling : MonoBehaviour
{
    public NaviManager naviManager;
    public float speed;
    public float timeToStopRolling;
    public string onCollisionState;

    private Rigidbody rb;
    private bool isTouching = false;
    private bool stopRollingCoroutine = false;
    private bool stopRolling = false;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (naviManager.crateOpenOnce)
        {
            if (isTouching)
            {
                if(stopRollingCoroutine == false)
                {
                    StartCoroutine(WaitBeforeStopRolling());

                    stopRollingCoroutine = true;
                }

                if (stopRolling == false)
                {
                    rb.AddForceAtPosition(Vector3.right * speed * Time.deltaTime, transform.position);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                rb.velocity = rb.velocity * 0.95f * Time.deltaTime;
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.name == "Crate_0_0")
        {
            onCollisionState = "Touching !!!";

            isTouching = true;
        }

        if(collision.gameObject.name == "Stair")
        {
            speed = 100;
        }
    }

    IEnumerator WaitBeforeStopRolling()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(timeToStopRolling);

        stopRolling = true;
    }
}
```

I want to stop the transform from rolling at once or slowly but the goal is to make it stop rolling after X seconds.

After for example 3 seconds I'm setting the flag stopRolling to true and I used a breakpoint and it is true but the object is kept rolling.

Should I remove force somehow to make it stop?

The object that is rolling has a Rigidbody Use Gravity set to true. and a Sphere Collider.

I didn't do anything to make it start rolling. The object starts rolling once he touches the "Crate_0_0" once the flag isTouching is true.

I also tried to set both velocity and angularVelocity to Vector3.zero but it didn't stop it either.

```cs
IEnumerator WaitBeforeStopRolling()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(timeToStopRolling);

    rb.velocity = Vector3.zero;
    rb.angularVelocity = Vector3.zero;

    stopRolling = true;
}
```

Setting the Rigidbody isKinematic to true stop the object but that stop it at once. What if I want to stop the object slowly smooth instead of using isKinematic?

Comment: Setting the Rigidbody isKinematic to true stop the object but that stop it at once. What if I want to stop the object slowly smooth instead using isKinematic ?

Comment: you could apply an inverse force over time, possibly `-rigidbody.velocity * slowSpeed * Time.deltaTime`